# Get meta value of td (React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, metadata

Lets say I already have this  `<td meta="Special forces" >View</td>` and I need to get  meta.
How can I get it?
I am using react js and using `document.getelementByTagName()` is bit tricky. Advice please

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted to figure this out on your own before asking?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get every `td` element with `meta` attirbute, you can use `querySelector` with `td[meta]`.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('td[meta]');
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<table><tr><td meta="Special forces" >View</td></tr></table>
```

btw, there is no `meta` attribute in `td` tag in HTML5.

Comment: my aim now is to get meta. I have done this for now

let metadata=da.target.outerHTML
    // console.log(metadata)
    metadata = metadata.replace(/<td value="/, '');
    metadata = metadata.replace(/">View<\/td>/, '');
    metadata=JSON.parse(metadata.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using React, you can make use of **ref**. Please find the below example which I've tried.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current.getAttribute("meta"));
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td ref={ref} meta="Special forces">
              View
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try to look the code here in Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-pine-r3jzh?file=/src/App.js) which I tried.

Comment: If you use a React ref why would you still query the DOM, it completely defeats the point of using the ref. You can just `ref.current.getAttribute("meta")` directly.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese for noticing that. I didn't thought of it. Updated the code. :)